# Boot time too long

Tags: linux-mint, boot, usb, mouse, cinnamon

I changed my OS from Win10 to Linux Mint "Cinnamon" (twice! first time, after 2 weeks of completely happy experience, I got a genius idea to delete one of multiple version of python, which of course blew up the system); everything is fine now, except the boot time. After turning on, the screen stays completely dark for a minute or so before actually starting loading Mint.

I think I messed up something when installing the OS. I installed from USB, but in "compatibility mode", I don't know if this changes something?

I also thought, may be BIOS is trying to boot (again) from USB, but since it's not there, it takes long time, but I have already changed BIOS settings to "default", and this didn't change anything.

Also, first time when I installed Linux, I got a nice screen just after launching computer, asking which OS I would like to launch? I don't have it anymore.

Is there any way to fix things to make all work smootly?

**EDIT**

My mouse is the cause of problem. I don't know why, but When I un-plug the mouse, the boot happens very quickly. When mouse is plugged, the boot time, at least, is multiplied by 3.

If someone have an explanation of this behaviour, or know how to fix the nice strat-up menu for choosing OS, it would be great :)

**EDIT 2**

Output from `systemctl --failed:0 loaded units listed`
Output from `systemd-analyze blame`: well, a whole bunch of rows with time spent on each task, but not very different from each other

output from `systemd-analyze` mouse plugged IN:`Startup finished in 2min 56.518s (firmware) + 4.308s (loader) + 4.750s (kernel) + 13.136s (userspace) = 3min 18.715s`

output from `systemd-analyze` mouse NOT plugged:Startup finished in 25 seconds, "firmware finished in 4 seconds

Comment: What is the output of `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemctl --failed` ?